# How to access Transmission runing behind a NAT from external PC

Tags: port-forwarding, forwarding, xforwarding, transmission

I have two PCs at two different places. Ons is behind a firewall I cannot (place X) control and the other is at my home.

Transmission has a way of adding/ removing torrents using a web interface. 
http://127.0.0.1:9091/transmission/

Now I can use the above url when I am using the PC X but when I am at home I cannot control Transmission.

I have a third Amazon EC2 instance which can be used to set up tunneling or back SSH sessions.

I understand I can easily do this using team viewer. But that way I will not learn anything.

I want to do some data forwarding through ports and get the web interface of transmission from my home PC which has a public IP.

Amazon server has a public IP as well. All PCs have admin privileges and they all run Linux.

I've previously controlled PC X using a back SSH session to my Amazon server and then forward SSHing from my home to Amazon Server thereby forwarding my SSH packets to PC X. can something similar be done for this as well?

Comment: Is there anything that stops you from setting up tunneling for port 9091, just like you did for port 22 (SSH) ?

Comment: no actually not. Is there a method to set up tunneling to forward http / https traffic?

Comment: Exactly the same you used to forward SSH. Only the ports change.